# Suddenly docker tail command stops giving live docker container logs in some of the services

Tags: docker, containers, tail

Hope everyone doing well!

I have production environment which runs multiple docker containers on the ubuntu server. Since last 5 to 6 days I am facing issue in some of the services where suddenly docker container stops giving me live logs using below command and service is not working.

```
docker tail --100 -f container_name
```

It is working very well since last 6 months but suddenly this is happening where I am not able to fetch live logs and service stops working which is affecting my production environment.

Appreciate any help who has an idea to resolve this issue.

Thank-you in advance!